# 2.79b Blender texture paint stroke oddity

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

https://i.stack.imgur.com/URRbB.png
Strokes have these "bounding box" or "update area" like discolorations. They are cleared once I Undo, and so remove one of the strokes. Only in UV/Image Editor, does not appear in 3D view.

Edit: It was something with the file itself it seems, for when I copied my work onto startup file those Discolorations (they are only visual, not color information) in UV/image editor did not appear anymore.
Its not the first time that I run into it, will try to be more conscious of when it happens and update here.

Comment: Please show a Blender Screen capture of your work.  Show the Brush Settings.  Part of your statement is difficult to understand for me.

Comment: Images can be used in many ways.  You appear to have a UV Map and are painting off the UV Map which may be unusual and unintentional.  Please see a video tutorial on the UV Map which can be found on the famous site that has a name that rhymes with NooNube.

Comment: Suggestion.  See a tutorial on Blender Texture Paint . Web site mentioned above..  Blender gives you options to create brushes you like or dislike or understand or do not understand.  What seems like an oddity today for you maybe a desired feature in the future.  You might give a new title to your question such as ... I do not understand the Texture Paint Brush I have created.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion is to have a fresh start.
Delete the Brush in question and create a new one.  Use the new Brush and see if the problem persists.

You may have changed a setting unintentionally. There are many settings in Blender that you or I or some others may not have the time to track down at the moment. In the sense of triage you may have more important things to occupy your concerns.